# Partner Connector with OAuth and unique parameters

Tags: looker-studio

I would like to make a partner connector for Data Studio with OAuth as authentication method but 
I have a little problem as in my case authorization server is different for every user which means that following parameters are unique for every user: AuthorizationBaseUrl, TokenUrl, ClientId, ClientSecret.

Is it possible to make a partner connector with OAuth and make those parameters configurable before starting OAuth?

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: How would the connector determine the AuthorizationBaseUrl for a specific user?

Comment: Somehow the user must pass AuthorizationBaseUrl to the connector.

Answer (score 0):

Since your `AuthorizationBaseUrl` is different for each user, the only solution I can think of is to develop your own landing page for each user and use that as `AuthorizationBaseUrl`. From there, you can collect the correct URL from the user and redirect them as necessary.